# How to insert element so CSS is attached?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to take JSX and insert it into a DOM element outside of my app so it can be printed.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
ReactDOM.render(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(JSX), document.getElementById('print_area'));
```

In this, JSX is an object created by React. All the output looks correct, but the HTML markup is not acted on by the browser. No CSS or fomatting.

How can I do this so the browser applies the CSS to the new element?

I've also tried ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticHTML(JSX) but the results are the same.

Comment: can you show the code for `JSX`? are you using `className` attributes to add classes to elements that CSS can target?

Comment: The text generated by ReactDOMServer.renderToString(JSX) is perfectly valid. If I copy and paste it into an HTML file and load it, everything looks as it should. This has something to do with the CSS not attaching to generated HTML when it is inserted into 'print_area'.

Comment: The browser will apply the styles if the styles are available to the browser and they target the elements in your document correctly. In React you are likely either using some kind of CSS in JS solution or you are writing CSS code and putting classes on your JSX using `className`? Perhaps you can share the code in question?

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Thank you for your comments. The issue is connected to the call I listed. The HTML text being produced works perfectly when I manually insert it where it into the 'print_area' DIV. I am aware that inserting elements into the DOM can be tricky and there are considerations I just can't how they apply here so that I can get the generated HTML to work properly when it is added.

Comment: Where are the styles you are expecting to see in this scenario? Inline `style` tags? In a CSS stylesheet that is already loaded? In a new stylesheet that the inserted HTML is linking to? This seems like the critical detail.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Thanks for your comments. I realized I could take a VanillaJS approach and it works fine now.